# iPhone: Set Map zoom level on the base of distance

Tags: iphone, dictionary, zooming, distance

I want to set the zoom level of google map on the base of variable value so it show only part of map on start-up. Basically i want to show only surrounding area from user location.

For example if variable value is 30 mile, then map show only 30 mile surrounding area from current location and zoom in/out accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `MKCoordinateRegion` using the [`MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKitFunctionsReference/Reference/reference.html) function and pass it to the map view's `setRegion:animated:` method.

Note that `MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance` requires meters so you'll need to convert the miles to meters first.